# In Xcode 7.3.1 why are all warnings invisible in my .swift files

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode7, cocoapods

In our project which include a number of cocoapods, in our cocoapod files, in the Development Pods section, all warnings are suppressed in the source editor. The warnings appear in the actual build file, but when you click on one you go to the source file and there are no warnings present. Other included cocoapods show warnings. I've checked every build setting and all suppressions are default (no). I even forced inhibit_all_warnings in my pod file to false. But nothing will show any warnings at all. This is driving me nuts, it started happening recently, yet nothing accounts for why.

It does show errors, just not warnings.

Actually only two files in the whole project show warnings. The error tab only shows these. All other 150+ warnings in the whole project do not show up in their source files, both languages.

Answer (score 0):

You should clean the project, using shift+command+k or go to the menubar select product, clean.

Comment: Delete derived data, clean, reboot, pretty much tried all that stuff. Still you get all the warnings in build but not in source files except for two.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing Xcode and if that doesn't help, reboot your computer. Check the App Store for any updates (like software or for Xcode). This may just be a bug in this specific Xcode. Unless using Xcode 7 is absolutely necessary, I suggest updating to Xcode 8 beta

Comment: No its the most recent everything. Xcode 8 is not usable as we have 10 other teams sharing the project.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not really sure what to suggest then. Does this problem occur on everyone's Xcode or just yours?

Comment: The two of us working together both have the issue. If you build just the development cocoapod you see the warnings. If you build the example app that includes it and the other pods then you only see warnings in two files, both in another pod. But I've checked every build setting and everything appears fine. It's very strange.